# Using Ruby on a string, how can I slice between two parts of the string using RegEx?

Tags: ruby, regex

I just want to save the text between two specific points in a string into a variable.  The text would look like this:

```
..."content"=>"The text I want to save to a variable"}]...
```

I suppose I would have to use scan or slice, but not exactly sure how to pull out just the text without grabbing the RegEx identifiers before and after the text. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var = mystring.slice(/\"content\"\=\>\".\"/)
```

Comment: Firstly, u need to use regex groups: /\"content\"\=\>\"(.*)\"/  However, there is a trick in Ruby that assigns directly to variables, and I don't remember it by heart.

Comment: Perhaps see thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692437/regex-with-named-capture-groups-getting-all-matches-in-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job

```
var = mystring[/"content"=>"(.*)"/, 1]
```

Note that:

- `.slice` aliases `[]`
- none of the characters you escaped are special regexp characters where you're using them
- you can "group" the bit you want to keep with `()`
- `.slice` / `[]` take a second parameter to pick a matched group

Comment: Thanks, that did it! You were right, I didn't need to escape all those other chars, much cleaner now.  Good to know the parameter that picks a matched group, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
your_text = '"content"=>"The text I want to save to a variable"'
/"content"=>"(?<hooray>.*)"/ =~ your_text
```

Afterwards, hooray local variable will be magically set to contain your text. Can be used to set multiple variables.

Comment: Upvote for showing me a new way to save a regex string into a variable, cool!

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match your string:

```
/\"content\"=>\"(.*)\"/
```

you can try rubular.com for testing

Comment: Needs a tweak if the string value might contain escaped double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to truncate a sentence. You can split the sentence either on punctuation, or even on words.

```
mystring.split(".")
mystring.split("word")
```